# PosgresSQL memory leak

Tags: c++, postgresql

I am running a system written in c++ that is continuously inserting large amounts of data into my database and at the same time querying the database for updated results. My problem is that the postgres threads started in this process continuously use more and more memory. I need to know how to correct this problem. The following is a much simpler program that demonstrates this issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <tbb/tbb_thread.h>//intel parallel studio class for parel

#include "libpq-fe.h"
#include "libpq/libpq-fs.h"

class Inserter{
public:
    void operator()(){
        PGconn* conn = PQconnectdb("user=postgres password=1234");
        int i=0;
        while(1){
            std::stringstream insert;
            insert << "INSERT INTO tmp (value) VALUES (" << i%250 << ");";
            PGresult* res=PQexec(conn,insert.str().c_str());
            if (PQresultStatus(res) == PGRES_FATAL_ERROR){
                std::cout << "Error in inserting data:\nError code: " << PQresStatus(PQresultStatus(res)) << "Error Message: " << PQerrorMessage(conn);
                PQclear(res);
                PQfinish(conn);
                return;
            }
            PQclear(res);
            i++;
        }
    }

};
class Queryer{
public:
    void operator()(){
        PGconn* conn = PQconnectdb("user=postgres password=1234");
        int j=0;
        while (1){
            std::stringstream query;
            query << "SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE id>" << j%1000 << ";";
            PGresult* res=PQexec(conn,query.str().c_str());
            if (PQresultStatus(res) == PGRES_FATAL_ERROR){
                std::cout << "Error in searching data:\nError code: " << PQresStatus(PQresultStatus(res)) << "Error Message: " << PQerrorMessage(conn);
                PQclear(res);
                PQfinish(conn);
                return;
            }
            PQclear(res);
            Sleep(10);
            j++;
        }
    }

};

void main(){
    //connect to Database
    PGconn* conn = PQconnectdb("user=postgres password=1234");

    //create table
    std::cout << "Creating table...\n";
    PGresult* res=PQexec(conn,"CREATE TABLE tmp (id SERIAL8 PRIMARY KEY,value INT);");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) == PGRES_FATAL_ERROR){
        std::cout << "Error in Creating table:\nError code: " << PQresStatus(PQresultStatus(res)) << "Error Message: " << PQerrorMessage(conn);
        //PQclear(res);
        //PQfinish(conn);
        //return;
    }
    PQclear(res);
    PQfinish(conn);

    std::cout << "Starting table filling thread...\n";
    //fill table with some data
    Inserter ins;
    tbb::tbb_thread filling(ins);
    Sleep(1000);
    // searching table ... here is where the memory leak is
    std::cout << "Starting table searching thread...\n";
    Queryer que;
    tbb::tbb_thread searching(que);

    while(true)
    {
        tbb::tick_count::interval_t t(1.0);
        tbb::this_tbb_thread::sleep(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think he means that the Postgres.exe memory consumption is growing, not his own application.

Comment: I am facing similar problem. As I using similar approach (Reader Writer thread), I can see there is memory leak happen through out my debugger. Have you come across any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to close your connections in some way?

Comment: He is closing them with PQfinish(conn); The problem is that this is not exception safe.

Comment: The operator()() functions only close it in case of an error.

Comment: if we closed connections for everytime we do a select or insert, the memory leak problem in postgres.exe would go away. However, in real-time application, the latency incurred from re-opening a connection for every query is too great that we have to keep the connection opened.

Comment: In that case you probably shouldn't open the connections in every call.

Rule of thumb: everytime you do Something *ptr = SomeFunction(), you need to do something to free memory before ptr goes out of scope.